# Intuition for vertex/set cover approximation algorithms

Tags: graphs, approximation

The best approximation algorithm for vertex cover is *randomly* choosing an edge and removing its vertices (picking the largest degree vertex actually is a worse approximation), but the best approximation algorithm for almost the identical problem of set cover does take the largest set.

How can we explain intuitively why picking the largest degree vertex doesn't result in a smaller (and thus better approximation) vertex cover, and why doesn't the same reasoning apply to sets?

Comment: For vertex cover, when you pick the largest degree vertex, you guarantee that you cover the "most" number of edges. Equivalently, for set cover, when you pick the set which has the maximum number of elements, you guarantee to cover all elements with fewer sets.

Comment: That's precisely why it's unintuitive though -- randomly choosing an edge is better than choosing the largest degree vertex to find the best approximation for the vertex cover.